# Calling EndConnect after BeginConnect

Tags: c#, sockets

According to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endconnect(v=vs.110).aspx), the `socket.EndConnect` method should be called in the `AsyncCallback` delegate provided in the original `socket.BeginConnect` call.

What is not clear (and the MSDN article is silent here) is whether `EndConnect` should be called after a timeout (and the socket is NOT connected). `socket.EndConnect` throws an exception in this case.

What is the proper procedure to follow after timeout? What are the consequences if `EndConnect` is not called (either after a successful connection or timeout without connection)? My code appears to work fine without calling `EndConnect`.

Here is some example code covering the main ideas in the question:

```
// Member variables
private static ManualResetEvent m_event;
private static Socket m_socket;

// Constructor of class
public static CMyTestConnection()
{
    // Create an event that can be used to wake this thread when the connection completes
    m_event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
}

private static void TestConnection(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create connection endpoint
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("200.1.2.3");    // Deliberately incorrect
    IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 12345);    // Also deliberately incorrect
    EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)ipep;

    // Attempt connection
    m_event.Reset();
    m_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    m_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
    m_socket.BeginConnect(ep, ConnectCompletedCallback, m_socket);
}

private static void ConnectCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // The asynchronous connection call has completed. Either we have connected (success) or
    // timed out without being able to connect (failure).
    m_event.Set();
    Socket s = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    if (s.Connected)
    {
        // Success...should EndConnect only be called here?
        s.EndConnect(ar);
    }
    else
    {
        // Or should EndConnect also be called here (in a try/catch block)?
        s.Close();  
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the timeout implemented? What _"resources, threads, handles, etc."_ are you trying to release? Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to completely understand your scenario. That said, if you call `BeginConnect()`, you need to call `EndConnect()`, period. You call to `EndConnect()` needs to be in try/catch so you can handle _expected_ exceptions, including one that gets thrown on a timeout before a connection can be established.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. The MSDN article does not specifically say to call `EndConnect` even if the socket is not connected. Neither does it use try/catch blocks in their examples. Nor is any information given about what the consequences are if `EndConnect` is not called. Hence the question for clarification. I'll edit the question so that the MSDN article does not need to be looked at.

Comment: Any call to a `.BeginXXX` method that does not throw an exception must be followed up with a call to the corresponding `.EndXXX` method to release any resources. The `.EndXXX` method could throw an exception that must be handled, that's fine. But don't leave asynchronous operations dangling. This is a general property of the asynchronous programming model, not specific to sockets. Sometimes, calling `.EndXXX` is functionally redundant (there are no resources to clean up, or maybe you know they'll all get discarded on a `Dispose`) but you can't know that in general; relying on it is bad style.

Comment: Incidentally, inferring anything from MSDN samples is often hopeless because the samples tend to be of low quality. In particular, they should almost never be used as examples of production-worthy code, even if (by some stroke of improbable fortune) they happen to be insightful demonstrations.

Comment: OK, thanks both (Jeroen and Peter). If you could knock together something along the lines of your answer, Jeroen, I'll accept it as the answer...and start using `EndConnect` in my handler immediately!

Comment: Test comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569157/calling-endconnect-after-beginconnect and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invited me to [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147150/room-for-alaind-and-peter-duniho). I am assuming this is the question to which you're referring, but it's hard for me to know for sure. Your message in the chat room doesn't have a real URL. I looked at your question links in your profile, and the only one I recognize is this one, which isn't closed at the moment. So there's no need to vote to re-open.

That said, the answer is still the same as already provided in the comments: you *always* call the `EndXXX` method when you've called `BeginXXX` (the few known exceptions don't apply here). There's nothing in your question, even after the recent edit, that would indicate what more you need.

You don't show how the timeout is implemented, so there's not even enough information to understand the code you  posted. But if you are closing the socket, thus causing your callback to be invoked where `EndConnect()` will throw an exception, you should be calling `EndConnect()`. Failing to do so can potentially leave unmanaged resources dangling, which would then eventually be exhausted, or at the very least lead to performance problems.

The source code for .NET is readily available, so you can easily examine [the implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,a218fda1129c0b0c) yourself. In the case of `Socket.EndConnect()`, we can see that for the current implementation, if the socket has already been disposed, all that happens is an exception is thrown. So, in theory, you could ignore sockets that have already been closed. I.e. this is an exception to the general concern about leaving resources dangling, in the specific "socket is already closed" scenario. But *only* if your timeout is implemented by closing the socket.

There are a couple of problems here though, related to race conditions:

1. Depending on how the timeout is implemented (you didn't share that part, so the question is still incomplete), you may have code that got as far as starting to call `Socket.Close()`, but which has not set the disposed flag. You'll be dealing with a connected socket that is about to become disconnected, and you need to have `try`/`catch` in place to handle that scenario.
2. Your callback assumes (it seems…again, there's not enough context in your question) that the `Connected` property is a reliable way to detect that there's been a timeout, but the `Connected` property could theoretically be reset to `false` after being connected, but before your callback gets to execute (e.g. some other type of error on the socket).

As far as the question of calling `EndConnect()` on a successful connection, that is much more clear: you *must* do so. If your code appears to work even though you haven't, that's just you getting lucky. We can see in the implementation that the `EndConnect()` method does useful work to configure the socket state when called after a successful connection, so if you fail to call the method, your socket will be in some indeterminate, incompletely configured state.

Naturally, if your timeout is implemented in some other way, where the socket is *not* closed before the callback is invoked, then you are in the same situation as if the connection had completed, and you *must* call `EndConnect()` to ensure that the appropriate cleanup and socket configuration occurs. I.e. that would be the same as the "successful connection" scenario.

The bottom line is, there is **zero** benefit to **not** calling `EndConnect()` in the event of a close/dispose-based timeout. The only hypothetical benefit might be that you can avoid `try`/`catch`, but you can't get away without that, because of the race conditions that exist. And if there's *not* such a timeout, not only is there not a benefit to not calling the method, there is real harm in failing to call it.

On a related note, there's not enough context in your question to make any real assessments of the rest of your code (since you didn't show how you're implementing the timeout, nor how the rest of your network I/O is handled). But I will say that in most cases, the "reuse address" option is unnecessary and should *not* be used. Most people wind up using it because they get into a situation where they can't start a new listening socket after they have somehow stopped a previous one, but that problem only comes up with the first listening socket and/or associated connected sockets have not been closed or shutdown correctly. The correct approach in that case is to handle the socket closure/shutdown correctly, not to add to the problem by setting "reuse address".

Comment: Thanks Peter. To answer your question "how is the timeout implemented", I honestly do not know. After setting up the socket and calling `BeginConnect`, I wait for the connection callback to fire (the `ConnectCompletedCallback` method). This happens within ms if IP/Port is valid but after ~20s (on my system) if not. I assume the timeout is defined by the OS or is a hidden default of the .NET socket itself. Couldn't see relevance of OS / .NET version from the MSDN documentation but if relevant am using Windows CE 6.0 and .NET CF 2.0.

Comment: It was not clear from your question that the "timeout" to which you referred was just the normal "failed to connect" behavior in the network API. (It was possible that you had implemented some additional timeout behavior in addition to that.) In that case, you fall into the "object is not disposed" category, where the `EndConnect()` method does real work, and you must call it to ensure all of the work the object wants to do at that point can in fact occur.